# Is "tactical awareness" an alias of "interceptions"?

Tags: fifa-14

I only find "interceptions" attribute on my FIFA 14 (Just like [this](http://www.futhead.com/14/players/5562/luiz-gustavo/)), but I notice many guys mentioned something called "tactical awareness" attribute ([example](http://fifanow.com/site/ultimate-team/all-fifa-14-in-game-player-statistics-explained/)).

I think it's an alias of "interceptions" in fact, but I'm not sure. So, is it an alias?

Comment: I don't know about Fifa, but in general football terms, I'd say no, they are definitely not synonymous. Although you might reasonably expect somebody with high "tactical awareness" to get more interceptions just by virtue of being in the right place. Assuming your tactics are sensible, of course.

Comment: An example of "tactical awareness" might be playing with a flat back four, a defender with high tactical awareness will know when to step up to trip the off-side trap while a defender with low tactical awareness might not an end up playing a striker on-side.

Answer (score 2):

So here is the answer to the best of my knowledge, They are definately different things as in reality, Like user85756 mentioned in the comments of the OP Tactical awareness is the ability to play the teams tactics better whether it be on the counter attack or the offside trap, It is akin to the all important positioning stat for strikers but more important for defenders.

Interceptions on the other hand is the defenders ability to actually intercept the ball if he is in the correct position.

The best defender will have a combination of both of these so that the player is in the right position and can execute.

You will find on most forums that the TA stat is largely debateble whether it actually effects ingame play but i have found that defenders with a much higher stat play the offside trap much better than the ones with a low one.

[Source for Tactical awareness](http://fifanow.com/site/ultimate-team/all-fifa-14-in-game-player-statistics-explained/)

Comment: `You will find on most forums that the TA stat is largely debateble whether it actually effects ingame play`, I just wanna, how to see the stat TA of a player...?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think they are. According to what I researched: Tactical Recognition: For the people which have established your teams' route to shorter passing and you have got an individual prosperous in Tactical Awareness, he'll be nearer towards the ball much more normally when compared to the usual participant with lower Tactical Consciousness.

So in this case, I would say they are the opposite: Tactical Awareness is the ability to have your own players well positioned for a pass... Interception meaning you read the opponent to know where the pass is going and take possession.

Hope this answers the question :)

Comment: What sources did you research?

Comment: Several, including official sites, and you have a bunch of details and controversy if this actually influences in-game, but this came out on a blog specific to coin buying for the game, where they went through the things that would basically win you the game easier. It makes total sense, but of course, if then some other attributes override it... I don't know. I was just focused on answering the OP :)

Comment: I'd recommend adding in the links that influenced your answer.  That ensures we know where this information comes from, and we're rather big on proper attribution.

Comment: Sure, [here](http://fifacoinsxboxe.blogspot.com/2013/09/tactical-awareness-vision-stability-and.html), have nothing to hide :) maybe not what the OP was looking for, but... it's what I have to offer in all due honesty